# Amazon SES RawMessage: Missing required header 'From'

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use Aws\Ses\SesClient;
use Aws\Ses\Exception\SesException;
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

if(!function_exists("sendmailalexraw")){

function sendmailalexraw($email,$subject,$messages,$definesender)
{



// Replace sender@example.com with your "From" address. 
// This address must be verified with Amazon SES.
$sender = $definesender;           
$sendername = 'Alex';

// Replace recipient@example.com with a "To" address. If your account 
// is still in the sandbox, this address must be verified.
$recipient = $email;    

// Specify a configuration set.
$configset = 'ConfigSet';

// Replace us-west-2 with the AWS Region you're using for Amazon SES.
$region = 'eu-west-1'; 

$subject = $subject;

$htmlbody = <<<EOD
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<h1>Hello!</h1>
<p>Please see the attached file for a list of customers to contact.</p>
</body>
</html>
EOD;

$textbody = <<<EOD
Hello,
Please see the attached file for a list of customers to contact.
EOD;

//// The full path to the file that will be attached to the email. 
$att = 'path/to/customers-to-contact.xlsx';

// Create an SesClient.
$client = SesClient::factory(array(
    'version'=> 'latest',     
    'region' => $region
));

// Create a new PHPMailer object.
$mail = new PHPMailer;

// Add components to the email.
$mail->setFrom($sender, $sendername);
$mail->addAddress($recipient);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $htmlbody;
$mail->AltBody = $textbody;
$mail->addAttachment($att);
$mail->addCustomHeader('X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET', $configset);

// Attempt to assemble the above components into a MIME message.
if (!$mail->preSend()) {
    echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    // Create a new variable that contains the MIME message.
    $message = $mail->getSentMIMEMessage();
}

// Try to send the message.
try {
    $result = $client->sendRawEmail([
        'RawMessage' => [
            'Data' => $messages
        ]
    ]);
    // If the message was sent, show the message ID.
    $messageId = $result->get('MessageId');
    echo("Email sent! Message ID: $messageId"."\n");
} catch (SesException $error) {
    // If the message was not sent, show a message explaining what went wrong.
    echo("The email was not sent. Error message: "
         .$error->getAwsErrorMessage()."\n");
}

}
}



$email='example@gmail.com';
$subject='abc';
$messages='xyz';
$definesender='info@verifieddomain.net';
sendmailalexraw($email,$subject,$messages,$definesender);


?>
```

I am trying to send RawMessage with Amazon SES but I get :

**The email was not sent. Error message: Missing required header 'From'.**

Sender I use it's verified, my Amazon SES it's active  (out of sendbox ) .

I am needing to send as RAW Message to create unsubscribe option for emails I am sening.  As I read from documentation it have to be raw email to be able to add this parameters.Thank you !

Comment: After `$message = $mail->getSentMIMEMessage();`, print what `$message` contains and inspect it visually.  Does it have a properly-formed `From: ...` header?  The error suggests that it does not.

Answer (score 1):

You have to base64 encode the message :

```
$result = $client->sendRawEmail([
    'RawMessage' => [
        'Data' => base64_encode($messages)
    ]
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using AWS Ses, you could do it this way:

```
    define('SENDER', 'Your name<a@a.com>');
    define('RECIPIENT', 'b@b.com');
    define('CCLIST', 'c@c.com');

    define('REGION','your region');

    define('SUBJECT','Your subject goes here');
    $bodytext = "<h2>Your body goes here.</h2>" . PHP_EOL;
    $bodytext .= "<p>Append as many rows as you want</p>";

    define('BODY',$bodytext);


    $client = SesClient::factory(array(
            'version'=> 'latest',
            'region' => 'your region'
    ));

    $request = array();
    $request['Source'] = SENDER;
    $request['Destination']['ToAddresses'] = array(RECIPIENT);
    $request['Destination']['CcAddresses'] = array(CCLIST);
    $request['Message']['Subject']['Data'] = SUBJECT;
    $request['Message']['Body']['Html']['Data'] = BODY;

    try {
        $result = $client->sendEmail($request);
        $messageId = $result->get('MessageId');
        echo("Email successfully sent! Message ID: $messageId"."\n");

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo("The email was not sent. Error message: ");
        echo($e->getMessage()."\n");
    }
```