# How to send mail from aws server using php mail()?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Using php mail() I am able to send email from cpanel but the same code is not working in aws server. below is my code.

```
$to="mymail@gmail.com";
$subject="Hello";
$message="Welcome Onboard";
$headers  = "From:Test<test@gmail.com>\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

$retval = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
return $retval;
```

Comment: `code is not working in aws server` what is not working, do you get error or something?

Comment: I am getting message as email sent successfully, but I am not receiving it in inbox

Comment: What is your instance of PHP set up to send mail with? If it's something like `sendmail`, is that actually installed on your server? Does AWS even allow sending mail from its servers? I did find a reference for sending email on AWS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-sdk-php.html

Answer (score -2):

You should be able to send `sendmail()` in AWS but the service needs to be up and running in your instance. 
Check [this link](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=109317) on how to get that started.

Alternatively, you could use AWS SeS service, which works really well and is more robust. 
Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58985896/amazon-ses-rawmessage-missing-required-header-from/58987318#58987318) to see how that can be accomplished (pretty simple).

Comment: Linked is broken